# How can I force an android app to use only a certain account to use google drive api (GDAA)?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an android app that generates files and I need to upload these files to google drive but using only an specific account. Is there a way to do this?

For now I have this code that allows me to choose the account :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

}
 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The GoogleApiClient uses the google accounts present on the device to connect and thus the Drive Android API will only be able to fetch/create files on those account. By definition if you want all the clients to backup to a single Drive account, all those client should have the credentials for that account which is not safe.

It sounds like you need a single server endpoint where your clients can connect to and post any data. Look into storage APIs provided by firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) if you want a pre-cooked solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going to check the alternative you suggest.

Comment: I was viewing for firebase capabilities and is not what I need. I forgot to tell that every user need to upload files to a central repository and an administrator (PC)can see all the files uploaded for all users